# flask restplus path variable default value

Tags: swagger, flask-restplus

How to set the default value for a path variable with Flask restplus?

For example, with the below:

```
@api.route('/calendars/coordinates/<string:latitude>/<string:longitude>/years/<string:year>')
class DailyCalendarHandler(Resource):
  get_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
  get_parser.add_argument('timezone', type=str, default='Asia/Calcutta', help='Example: Asia/Calcutta', location='args', required=True)
  get_parser.add_argument('encoding', type=str, default='devanagari', help='Example: iast, devanagari, kannada, tamil', location='args',
                          required=True)

  @api.expect(get_parser)
  def get(self, latitude, longitude, year):
    args = self.get_parser.parse_args()
    city = City("", latitude, longitude, args['timezone'])
```

How do I set default for year, latitude and longitude?

If it were a request variable, one could do the below:

```
get_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
get_parser.add_argument('output_transliteration', location='args', default='devanagari', help='devanagari/slp1/iast/hk/wx/itrans/kolkata/velthuis')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define multiple URL rules above your class and define defaults for arguments. Something like:

```
@api.route('/calendars/coordinates', defaults={'latitude':123, 'longitude': 56})
@api.route('/calendars/latitude/<string:latitude>/longitude/<string:longitude>/years/<string:year>')
    class DailyCalendarHandler(Resource):

  def get(self, latitude, longitude, year='2017'):
```

Comment: While this method works in terms of API calls with `curl` ... it really bugs me that the generated swagger ui still displays the second parameter with a `*required` tag.

Comment: @DebanjanBasu Path parameters are always required. You can't document a default value for them. There needs to be separate routes.